# Customize global search

Tags: lightning, user, search, global-search, search-layout

In the global search result shown in type ahead/auto complete search, how do I customize the field shown in second row. It generally shows, object type and one more field. For example, if I type for a user name, it show name in first row, type as User as second row, followed by title. But instead of title, if I want to show lets say city and state, how do I customize it? Where is this setting stored?

I tried updating the search result layout for the user object, but that is not reflecting on the global search's auto complete list. It still shows User:title in second row. Please let me know how to customize it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure there are two flavors of results that Global Search shows: items that come from the Recent Items of the Object and items that are not Recent Items. The items that come from Recent Items do not have Secondary Field. The items that are not Recent Items can have a Secondary Field and that can be configured.

> NOTE The secondary field provides context about the record. For example, the phone number for a contact appears under the contact’s name. Admins choose which field is shown when customizing the search results layout. The secondary field doesn’t appear for recent items or when the search results layout for the object isn’t specified. It also doesn’t appear when the field selected is a formula field, HTML link, image field, picklist, or long-text field. If the list of records in instant results includes recent items and other suggested records, users see a mix of results with and without secondary fields.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_instant_results.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null